# C++ std::shared_ptr and vector crash

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

Why this code crash?

```
class Point {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
};

class Edge {
public:
    Point org;
    Point dst;

    Edge(const Point& org, const Point& dest) {
        this->org = org;
        this->dst = dest;
    }
};

class Box {

    private:

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Edge>> _edges;

    void _init(const Point& lb, const Point& rt) {
        std::cout << "Initialize Box ... " << std::endl;

        // CRASH SOMEWHERE HERE ...

        this->_edges.reserve(4);

        this->_edges[0] = std::make_shared<Edge>(lb.x, lb.y, rt.x, lb.y);
        this->_edges[1] = std::make_shared<Edge>(rt.x, lb.y, rt.x, rt.y);
        this->_edges[2] = std::make_shared<Edge>(rt.x, rt.y, lb.x, rt.y);
        this->_edges[3] = std::make_shared<Edge>(lb.x, rt.y, lb.x, lb.y);

        std::cout << "Box object initialized" << std::endl;
    }

    public:
    Box(const Point& lb, const Point& rt) {
        this->_init(lb, rt);
    }
};
```

Comment: Crash at `this->_edges[0] = std::make_shared<Edge>(lb.x, lb.y, rt.x, lb.y);` and error segfault I suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reserve` reserves space for vector elements, but doesn't add any accessible elements to the vector. The size is still zero, so that your accesses to `_edges[0]` etc. are out of bounds.

Instead, either use `resize` to resize the vector, using your existing code to reassign the elements:

```
this->_edges.resize(4);

this->_edges[0] = std::make_shared<Edge>(lb.x, lb.y, rt.x, lb.y);
// and so on
```

or use `push_back` to add elements:

```
this->_edges.reserve(4);

this->_edges.push_back(std::make_shared<Edge>(lb.x, lb.y, rt.x, lb.y));
// and so on
```

or assign from an initialiser list

```
this->_edges = {
    std::make_shared<Edge>(lb.x, lb.y, rt.x, lb.y),
    // and so on
};
```

or simplify the code to initialise it in the initialiser list, where such things belong

```
Box(const Point& lb, const Point& rt) :
    _edges {
        std::make_shared<Edge>(lb.x, lb.y, rt.x, lb.y),
        // and so on
    }
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

`vector::reserve` reserves space but doesn't actually resize the array. Try using `resize` instead.